# Show similarity of triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

We first fold a square piece of paper in the middle, so that two congruent rectangles are created.

Then we fold $A$ onto midpoint $B$ of side $EC$ and mark points $D$, $F$, $G$ and $I$.

[image]

(a) Show that the triangles $\triangle IHG$, $\triangle BDC$ and $\triangle BEF$ are similar.

(b) Show that $|BD|:|BC|:|CD|=3:4:5$.

(c) Show that $|HF|=\frac{1}{3}\cdot |HE|$.

$$$$

At (a) we have that the triangles $\triangle BDC$ and $\triangle BEF$ are similar because:

- The angles $\angle BEF$ and $\angle BGD$ are equal , they are both right angles.
- It also holds that $|AG|=|BD|+|DG|$, $|EH|=|EF|+|FG|+|GH|=|EF|+|GI|+|GH|$ (since $|FG|=|GI|$, or not?), $|EG|=|EB|+|BG|=2|EB|=2|BG|$.

  So we get that $\frac{|EB|}{|EF|}=\frac{|GB|}{|EF|}$. How can we continue?

Comment: It's helpful to augment the final image with an element from a previous stage: let $J$ be the point where $H$ went upon folding. Then $(a)$ is accomplished with a simple angle chase that passes through right(!) $\triangle FGJ$. For $(b)$, note the relation between $|BD|$ and $|AD|$, and thus between $|BD|$ and $|CD|\;(=|AC|-|AD|)$; then invoke Pythagoras. For $(c)$ use the $3:4:5$ proportionality of $\triangle FBE$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Comment: I didn't mean to abandon you by leaving your other comment-questions unanswered. I'm glad you got the help you needed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if showing the sides being proportional is possible (at least I haven't put much effort to it yet. I might come back to it). The angle-angle(-angle) approach seems easier.

Also, I think you've typo'd. It should be $ \lvert AC\rvert = \lvert BD\rvert + \lvert DC\rvert $, etc.

---

Note that $\angle DBF$ is also a right angle, which, by symmetry, is the same as the right angle at A.

$\angle EBF = 90^\circ - \angle DBC$,

and hence $\angle EFB = 90^\circ - \angle EBF = \angle DBC$.

Together with the right angles at E and C, we have $\triangle BDC \sim \triangle FBE$.

As to why $\triangle IGH$ is also similar to the two triangles mentioned, think about the small triangle that went out of the square after folding the paper, say we call it $\triangle FGX$. By symmetry, $\triangle FGX \cong \triangle IGH$. Then it should be pretty straight-forward to show that $\triangle FGX \sim \triangle FBE$.

Comment: Why is $\angle DBF$ a right angle?

Comment: By folding the paper along $DG$, the right angle at $A$ will "land" on $\angle DBF$, hence they have the same measure. In fact, it's the same reasoning that $\lvert AD\rvert = \lvert BD\rvert$, or $\lvert FG\rvert = \lvert GI\rvert$. It might be helpful if you have a piece of square paper handy and try folding it yourself.

Comment: Ahh I see!! At question (b) how could we get that relation? It is not clear to me. Do we have to check how the sides of that right triangle are proposed? But how? As for question (c) we have that $|HE|=|FE|+|HF|$. To get the desired result we have to show that $|FE|=2|HF|$, right? Do we have to do something similar as in question (b) ?

Comment: Part (b): I'll expand on Blue's comment, a.k.a. "basically" telling you the answer. You're on the right track of checking $\triangle BCD$. Let's suppose $\lvert BC\rvert =1$. How long is $\lvert AC\rvert$? And suppose $\lvert CD\rvert =x$, using the fact that $\lvert BD\rvert =\lvert AD\rvert $, how long is $\lvert BD\rvert$? Then by Pythagorean theorem, you should be able to solve for $x$ and get the result.

Comment: Part (c): if we continue our assumption of $\lvert BC\rvert =1$, then by the previous parts you should be able to calculate $\lvert FE\rvert$ and $\lvert FH\rvert$. Particularly think about part (a).

Of course, as proofs goes, you can't quite outright state $\lvert BC\rvert =1$. I only picked it because it's convenient.

Comment: As for part (b) : We have that $| AD| = | BD|$ and  $|AC|=|AD|+|CD| \Rightarrow |AC|=| BD|+|CD| \Rightarrow |CD|=|AC|-| BD|$. 
The triangle $\triangle BCD$ is a right triangle so from Pythagoras we get:  \begin{align*}|BC|^2+|CD|^2=|BD|^2 &\Rightarrow |BC|^2+(|AC|-| BD|)^2=|BD|^2 \\ & \Rightarrow |BC|^2+|AC|^2-2\cdot |AC|\cdot | BD|+|BD|^2=|BD|^2 \\ & \Rightarrow |BC|^2+|AC|^2-2\cdot |AC|\cdot | BD|=0 \end{align*} How do we continue? Or do we have to solve for an other length?

Comment: Or have I understood the hint wrongly?

Comment: You're one step away! What's the relation between $\lvert BC\rvert$ and $\lvert AC\vert$?

Comment: Ahh so we have that $|BC|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot |AC|$, right?

Comment: Correct! Now substitute that relation back where you left off, do some algebra, and you should be really close finishing off part (b).

Comment: We get \begin{align*}|BC|^2+(2\cdot |BC|)^2-2\cdot (2\cdot |BC|)\cdot | BD|=0 7&\Rightarrow |BC|^2+4\cdot |BC|^2-4\cdot |BC|\cdot | BD|=0 \\ & \Rightarrow 5\cdot |BC|^2-4\cdot |BC|\cdot | BD|=0 \\ & \Rightarrow 5\cdot |BC|^2=4\cdot |BC|\cdot | BD| \\ & \Rightarrow 5\cdot |BC|=4\cdot | BD| \\ & \Rightarrow \frac{| BD|}{|BC|}=\frac{ 5}{4}\end{align*} right? This is not the esult that we want, is it?

Comment: Almost, if $\lvert BD\rvert :\lvert BC\rvert = 5:4$, what would $CD$ be?
(P.S. I don't think what you're trying to prove is correct, because obviously $\lvert BD\rvert$ is the longest of the three lengths. But the end result it similar enough that I didn't bother mentioning it)
(P.P.S, I'd prefer not to give any more hints from this point on. Try looking back at the question and what you've worked on, and you'll solve this problem. After all MSE isn't really an answer-your-homework-for-you site)

Comment: We have that $|BC|=\frac{4}{5}\cdot |BD|$, right?

Comment: And we also get that $|CD|=\frac{3}{5}\cdot |BD|$. Do these two relations mean that $|BD|:|BC|:|CD|=3:4:5$ ?

Comment: I am asking that because Ihaven'treally understood what $|BD|:|BC|:|CD|=3:4:5$ means.Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Hmm... I see. So $\lvert BD\rvert :\lvert BC\rvert :\lvert CD\rvert$ should be equal to $5:4:3$, and not $3:4:5$, as in the question itself is set wrong. What the ratio means is (and sorry if it sounds too elementary), if you plug in some actual lengths, say $\lvert BD\rvert =10$cm, then you'll get $\lvert BC\rvert = 8$cm and $\lvert CD\rvert = 6$cm; or if you plug in $\lvert BD\rvert =5$cm, you'll get $\lvert BC\rvert = 4$cm and $\lvert CD\rvert = 3$cm; etc. It's not too bad, as an intuition, to just assume the number in the ratio as actual lengths, so to make the calculations easier.

Comment: Ahh I see!! Thanks for the explanation! As for question (c) : From question (a) we get that $\triangle BDC \sim \triangle BEF$ and that's why the proportionality for $\triangle BDC$ holds also for $\triangle BEF$, i.e. $\lvert BF\rvert :\lvert EB\rvert :\lvert EF\rvert=5:4:3$, or not? Or do we not use here the proportionality?

Comment: You're correct that $5:4:3$ still holds true for $\triangle BEF$ (note: be careful of the correspondence of sides). Now, let's think the ratio as if it's actual lengths. We know that $\vert BC\vert=4$ units long. How long is $BE$, and then $EF$ and $EH$?

Comment: I got it!!! Thank you so much for your help!! :-)