# Geometry question involving folding a piece of paper

Tags: geometry

A square piece of paper has side length 1 and vertices A, B, C, and D in that order. As shown in the figure, the paper is folded so that vertex C meets edge AD at point C', and edge BC intersects edge AB at point E. Suppose that C'D = 1/3. What is the perimeter of AEC'?

[image]

I already have the answer so I'm moreso looking for the solution. Any pictures would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I already have the answer so I'm moreso looking for the solution." When you have an answer, you should include it. This can keep people from wasting time on a from-scratch derivation and focus on explaining a solution to you. (As a practical matter, it can help people construct figures without having to solve the problem first.)

Answer (score 4):

[image]Let's name the point between C and D, upon which the paper is folded, as point F.

$$ CF = C'F = x $$
$$ DF = CD - CF = 1-x$$

Using the Pythagoras's theorem in $\triangle C'DF$, we will see $x=\frac{5}{9}$.
Since $\triangle EAC'$ ~ $\triangle C'DF$, I can write:

**NOTE: P(object) is the perimeter of the object**

$$\frac{P(\triangle EAC')}{P(\triangle C'DF)} = \frac{AC'}{DF} $$
$$\frac{P(\triangle EAC')}{4/3} = \frac{2/3}{4/9} $$

$$ P(\triangle EAC') = 2 $$

Comment: The ubiquitous 3-4-5 triangle strikes again.

Comment: Please format answers using MathJax (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), not an image of hand-written equations.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for your input. I revised accordingly

Comment: @Joffan: Interestingly, [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3955532/409) has a similar folded-square setup. But while the current question folds $C$ to a trisection point $C'$ and creates what turns out to be midpoint $E$, the other has $C'$ a midpoint and $E$ a trisector. The $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle is a key feature of the other configuration as well.